# AJAX call without success field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi all is it possible to call a an ajax call without using success?
ie from:

```
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/project/test/auto",
                                data: data,
                                success: function(msg){
                                   //window.location.replace(msg);
                                }
                             });
```

to something simply like:

```
                           $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "/project/test/auto",
                                    data: data,

                                 });
```

To give reasoning - I have written some php to insert items into a database and then redirect to another page, I don't want to have to re-write the same code again to insert into the DB and then redirect in JS.

Comment: Have you tried your second code?

Comment: Sending a redirect in server-side code that's accessed using an XMLHttpRequest generally doesn't result in the actual web page changing to the new location.

Comment: sure guess so Ill give it a go - was just assuming it wouldn't work

Comment: @TotalNewbie, It tends to be better practice to try first before asking if something will work.

Comment: it doesn't work - cheers for the downvotes

Comment: @TotalNewbie remove that extra `,` after `data,`

Comment: Could you clarify which behaviour you are expecting here? Insert data to DB without redirecting user client side, is it???

Comment: @krishna The trailing comma will cause issues in IE (unless they've change that in IE10 or 11), but other browsers should work. Still a good idea to take it out of course.

Comment: The Ajax call can not redirect the page! If that is what you want, it will not work. If you want to redirect the page, why are you not just using a regular old form submission that has worked since the beginning of forms?

Comment: If you don't want to redirect using JS, then don't use AJAX. Just have whatever action that triggers the ajax call link the user to that page, and insert the data into the DB there... or redirect the user from PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can redirect using PHP within ajax call.

It would be best to create a function out of DB insert and then with ajax call a page that executes that function and returns success:true in json for example. After that, redirect in success part of your ajax call. You can later call the same DB insert function from within your PHP code.

Answer (score 4):

`jQuery.post()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post( "/project/test/auto", data );
```